# "Reduction of"? "Reduction in"? Either? Different?

Tags: prepositions, in-of

For example: "This has led to a reduction **in/of** the severity of poverty."

I tend to think "a reduction **in**" refers more to intensity and number, whereas "a reduction **of**" emphasizes the action.

As in:

1) "The President called for a reduction **of** troops in the region." (Emphasis on what he wants the Pentagon to do.)

2) "The President is working toward a reduction **in** HIV cases." (Emphasis on fewer cases.)

1 and 2 are very similar, but there is a subtle difference. At least, to me. I can't find the grammar rules regarding whether or not there's a difference in these prepositions in this context. Maybe they're interchangeable?

Comment: You could do some research yourself. Google and Google Ngram investigations of "reduction/s P the number of"; "reduction/s P the severity of" etc should be useful.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I already did that, and got similar numbers. Same as with a site-specific search (i.e., nytimes.com). 

Unfortunately, Googling ain't what it used to be. First, there is a lot of bad English out there. Second, there are a lot of useless click-bait pages that deliver unrelated results.

Anyway, both "in" and "of" are possible. I'm trying to find out if there's any real distinction between them, not see how common they are.

Comment: Indeed, "reduction of troops" is an action whereas "reduction in HIV cases" is a result.

Comment: Maybe that's the distinction: Action vs. Result. ... I like that.

Comment: This [Wordreference.com_forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reduction-in-of-on.1597061/) article shows that there is a degree of interchangeability, but not total interchangeability of pronouns. I'd say that @human's suggestion is astute, but not the whole story.

Comment: Hmm. So, perhaps a case of collocation arising from ellipsis, e.g., "a reduction ***in the number of*** troops" becomes "a reduction ***of*** troops", etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth there is nothing about that description makes it clear, there is no clear rule explained. I'm surprised nobody has given clear answer to this question.

Comment: @Herman Toothrot After many years of being impressed by the idiosyncrasy of non-prototypical prepositional usages, I'd be very surprised if anyone here had found a compelling answer (unless someone had written a doctorate on this particular issue, doing months of analysis) and almost as surprised if a clear answer actually existed.

Comment: *I tend to think "a reduction in" refers more to intensity and number, whereas "a reduction of" emphasizes **the object noun.*** You have all but answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

As @lauir has mentioned in the comments, this is probably a result vs action comparison.

> reduction of troops

Somebody reduced the troops; **action**.

> reduction in troops

Something occurred to reduce the number of troops e.g. virus, losing war badly; **result**.

Although this can actually be used interchangeably to a **certain extent**, it depends on the context. This can be especially confusing, e.g. something caused someone to reduce the troops - action or result? This might lead to a indirect-direct comparison as well.

If it is direct e.g. losing war directly causes your army to drop in numbers - **result**.

If it is indirect e.g. drop in economy causes president to reduce troops sent out to war (no money therefore less food and resources) - **action**.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the question first:**

1. A Google books ngram search shows both *‘in’* and *‘of’* are used by different writers in different circumstances.
2. Certainly ‘reduction *in* the number‘ is more frequently used than ‘reduction *of* the number’, but I find the suggestion that *‘of’* pertains to the action of the subject completely unconvincing and not proven. In the poster’s example, “a reduction *of* troops *in* the region”, its use may purely be to avoid repetition of *in*.

**The obligatory “I wouldn’t say that”:**

I personally find ‘reduction *of*’ jarring in the example sentence. This is probably because “reduction of troops doesn’t really make sense” — it is their *number* that is being reduced.

So I would write

> “The President called for a reduction *in the number of troops* in the region.”

or, even better, using the original verb rather than making an abstract noun of it, and hence banishing the preposition entirely:

> “The President called for the number of troops in the region *to be reduced*.”

Likewise, with the other example one could write:

> “The President is working toward *reducing* the number of HIV cases.”

However, if I were a journalist I would write:

> “The President called for a *troop reduction* in the region.”

And, although I am normally opposed to using nouns as adjective, the phrase, “troop reduction”, is succinct and so common that I would probably put my journalist hat on. (Except that because of my chemical training, I tend to use ‘decrease’ rather than ‘reduce’ to avoid ambiguity.)