# achieve (at least some) reduction

Tags: meaning, collocation, in-of

In an article I am writing, I use the following sentence:

"Despite our hypothesis, the time-based switching strategy performs the best and **achieves at least 29% reduction** in falls."

I am confused with the bold part. Somehow it feels that "achieve" and "reduction" do not match well, a better match for "achieve" could be something like "achieves at least 85% of the target performance". Does the original sentence sound wrong? An alternative formulation could be

"Despite our hypothesis, the time-based switching strategy performs the best and **results in a 29% reduction** in falls."

However, here **in** is repeated twice and, for this reason, it does not sound nice either. Note that I do not use "reduction **of**" on purpose and according to the intuition described in [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298271/reduction-of-reduction-in-either-different) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I def like the second one best, perhaps because it feel like reduction should be a countable noun here (i.e. 'a reduction'). If you don't like the double 'in' what about 'it leads to a 29% reduction in falls' or 'it accomplishes...'

Comment: Thank you, "leads to" sounds best to me, but is it fine to say "it leads to at least 29% reduction in falls"?

Comment: That sounds very slightly strange, though totally understandable. I gather you don't like the phrase 'reduction of' ( something on the lines of: it leads to a reduction of at least 29% in the rate of falls). What about reformulating?:... and reduces the rate of falls by at least 29%.

Comment: Yes, reformulation sounds good! I slightly alter it as "...and reduces the number of falls by at least 29%" because the number of falls is different from the rate of falls.

Answer (score 0):

**reduction**   [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/reduction)

> [**countable/uncountable**] the process or result of making something
>   smaller or less in amount, size, importance, etc.
>
> reduction in:
>
> 'There has been a dramatic reduction in the birth rate.'
>
> reduction of:
>
> 'The treaty committed each side to a reduction of 30 percent in its
>   stock of weapons.'

Your example with a modifier works fine and avoids *in* or *of* (if that is your desire):

> "Despite our hypothesis, the time-based switching strategy performs
>   the best and achieves a 29% reduction in falls."